# $.connection.Hub undefine

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am using signal r in frame work  4.0. When i am calling my hub class(testhub) it display undefine. My jquery code is as bellow

```
<head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js") %>'></script>
             <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js") %>'></script>

             <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js") %>'></script>   
            <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js") %>'></script>

             <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
    var data = $.connection.tenantHub;
                    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
                    console.log(data); //undefine

            </script>
    </form>
```

I have global.asax which does not through any error on

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

I have hub class within Hubs folder as bellow.

```
[HubName("tenantHub")]
public class testhub:Hub
{
    public void send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addmessage(message);
    }
}
```

My package is as bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="1.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="1.0-rc1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Why are you resolving the SignalR script and the minified version?

Comment: because my web site is build on frame work 4.0.

Comment: I don't see the open tag for `<script>` Your HTML is not well-formed.

Comment: SignalR server-side app is a separate app from your web application. It should be bootstrapped separately, not through your global.asax. [Here is an example](https://github.com/fahadash/Ticker.FSharp/tree/master/Samples/SignalR.Ticker.FSharp) . Look at MyStartup.cs and Startup.cs. And look at Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs where you tell `Owin` to run your startup. If that is too complicated [Follow Damien Edwards MoveShape example](http://www.fahadash.com/2015/05/signalr-damien-edwards-moveshape-sample.html)

Answer (score 0):

The last compatible signalr version for .net Framework 4.0 is 1.2.2 :

Can you try to update your Signalr version by opening the NuGet Package Manager Console and typing :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Version 1.2.2
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2
```

A full chat example based on jquery 1.6.4 Fwk 4 and signalR 1 : http://www.bluelemoncode.com/2013/02/default.aspx

Moreover don't resolve twice js scripts (keep only minified or uncompressed depending on your environment):

```
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js") %>'></script>                 
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js") %>'></script>
```

Comment: I install                                                                                                  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Version 1.2.2
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.2.2                            it through error in global.asax                                                                error: A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name

Comment: You must remove the previous version before installing a new one. Anyway did you tried the project I sent you ?